# Strange blank area in double sided document

Tags: two-column

[image]What is the cause of the blank area on the left bottom of this page? In fact there is no line break or page break there.

The file is created by adding some arbitrary text into main.tex in the Latex template of Bioinformatics, downloaded here:

http://www.oxfordjournals.org/our_journals/bioinformatics/for_authors/cabios-template.zip

Here is an minimal example:

```
\documentclass{bioinfo}
\copyrightyear{2015} \pubyear{2015}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\access{Advance Access Publication Date: Day Month Year}
\appnotes{Manuscript Category}

\begin{document}
\firstpage{1}
\subtitle{Subject Section}

\title[short Title]{This is a title}
\author[Sample \textit{et~al}.]{Corresponding Author\,$^{\text{\sfb 1,}*}$, Co-Author\,$^{\text{\sfb 2}}$ and Co-Author\,$^{\text{\sfb 2,}*}$}
\address{$^{\text{\sf 1}}$Department, Institution, City, Post Code, Country and \\
$^{\text{\sf 2}}$Department, Institution, City, Post Code,
Country.}

\corresp{$^\ast$To whom correspondence should be addressed.}
\history{Received on XXXXX; revised on XXXXX; accepted on XXXXX}
\editor{Associate Editor: XXXXXXX}

\abstract{\textbf{Motivation:} \blindtext\\
\textbf{Results:} \blindtext
\textbf{Contact:} \href{name@bio.com}{name@bio.com}\\
\textbf{Supplementary information:} Supplementary data are available at \textit{Bioinformatics}
online.}

\maketitle

\section{Introduction}
\Blindtext
\end{document}
```

Comment: Could you reproduce the same behaviour with the `ipsum` package? If so, a [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) would be helpful.

Comment: Yes I added one MWE

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The provided class file has (in a couple of places)

```
\enlargethispage{-23pt}
```

which exactly accounts for this space.

No idea why it is there clearly the journal wants that gap, perhaps in the published version they overlay an image or copyright notice or some such.

it is anyway an intentional feature of the class file to have a white space there.

Note that the distribution of the class zip file contains many (old) standard latex files *without* their sources which is clearly against the spirit of the latex licence.